# display dropdown list in detail view (edit mode) asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have problem to display dropdown list in detail view (in edit mode) for datafield division, here the code :

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ENumber" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="125px" OnItemUpdated="DetailsView1_ItemUpdated" OnPageIndexChanging="DetailsView1_PageIndexChanging" >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEE8F5" Font-Bold="True" />
                <Fields>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ENumber" HeaderText="ENumber" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ENumber" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%#Eval("Division") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
```

' runat="server" />

```
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Division" HeaderText="Division" SortExpression="Division" />
                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
                </Fields>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            </asp:DetailsView>
```

here the sql data source for the dropdown :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="FindDivisionDataSource" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QMS_PanasonicConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Select Code_ID,Code_Desc FROM T_Master_Setup where Master_Code_ID = 'CD001'" runat="server" />
```

any idea ?

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @ChaseErnst dropdown list didn't display, still appear like input form

Comment: maybe I am missing something here, but I do not see a `DropDownList` inside your `DetailsView`

Comment: @ChaseErnst sorry I've edit the code,. the DropDownList did'nt display